# Generate a numbers starting from 1 and increasing until the end of the year, then repeat in the next year

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model named 'post' , and I want this model to have a field named "id_field" which will take automatic value start from 1 and increasing with every post saved until the end of the year, then start again from 1 in the next year and so on.

for example in 2020:

post_1 --> id_field = 1

post_2 --> id_field = 2

post_3 --> id_field = 3

.

.

.

post_n --> id_field = n

then when 2021 came:

post_n+1 --> id_field = 1

post_n+2 --> id_field = 2

post_n+3 --> id_field = 3

Sorry for my bad english and I hope I explained the problem correctly, thanks.

Comment: You can have a global counter variable and can reset it as soon as year changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

counter =0 #take this value from the database
this_year= 2019 #you can get this value from the database if you want
def new_post():
    global counter
    counter+=1
    # your code
    if datetime.datetime.now().year > this_year:
        this_year=datetime.datetime.now().year
        counter=0
```

Comment: that counter should be stored somewhere. Otherwise, it will start at 0 every time the program starts. Think power interruption.

Comment: best imho would be to read the last id_field value of the database, increase by one, or start over with zero if it's a new year